# Cron won't run codeignitier function?

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

When i try just controller without function, it works, but with function something is wrong.

```
0 * * * * php /home/31175-23437.cloudwaysapps.com/username/public_html/index.php historic //this works
* * * * * php /home/31175-23437.cloudwaysapps.com/username/public_html/index.php system runsystem //this don't works
```

I am sure that /system/runsystem works.

runsystem contains this code:

```
public function runsystem(){
    $systemid = $this->sys_model->getmailsystems();
    foreach($systemid->result() as $row){
        $this->system_options("right","1x2","EU",true,$row->sys_id);
    }
    $usersystems = $this->sys_model->getusersystems();
    foreach($usersystems->result() as $row){
        $email = $row->email;
        $subject = $row->subject;
        $message = $row->message;
        sendmail($email,$subject,$message);
    }       
}
```

Comment: What errors you got?

Comment: @JaydeepB. How can i check errors? I don't have permission to access log files...

Comment: print something at the start of runsystem function to test if function working or not.